# Tomcat 7 slow startup in JSF 2 project

Tags: jsf, servlets, tomcat7

I have recently switched my project from using (JSF 1.x + Tomcat6) to (JSF 2.x servletes + Tomcat7).

Since then, when I start Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Indigo, it takes 25 seconds. This is way too much longer than Tomcat 6 would take to start in the previous JSF 1.x setup.

The server spends the most time at:

```
22.03.2012. 10:00:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
```

What could be the reason for such slow startup?

Comment: Seems like slow Tomcat 7 startup problem can be resolved with "metadata-complete" set to "true" in the web.xml, like so: <web-app metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"... The problem is that Tomcat scans for annotations at startup, and this significantly slows it down. My time is cut down from 25 secs to 5 secs. (Will post this as answer in a few hours.)

Answer (score 5):

Seems like slow Tomcat 7 startup problem can be resolved with "metadata-complete" set to "true" in the web.xml, like so:

`<web-app metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"...`

The problem is that Tomcat scans for annotations at startup, and this significantly slows it down.

Here startup time is cut down from 25 secs to 5 secs.